Swiperjs breaks when setting up Conditional Layouts on a Webflow CMS Page
I have a Webflow CMS Collection page that I'm using for my blog. In the design, I had two different swiper.js slider types (defined individually in codesandbox) that were working perfectly until I tried to add conditional Layouts to the Collection Page on webflow. When I did that, one of the swiperjs sliders seemed to disconnect, while I could see the correct content, the slider no longer functioned, while the other slider remained working properly. When I deleted the second Layout content div, and republished, then both of the swiper sliders function properly again. I tried to give every sider it's own class, and even it's own ID name, but nothing seems to work when I publish, and I would really like to have the Layout Options for the blog layout. Has anyone had this issue? Help? Thanks ;)
When I deleted the second Layout content div, and republished, then both of the swiper sliders function properly again. I tried to give every sider it's own class, and even it's own ID name, but nothing seems to work when I publish, and I would really like to have the Layout Options for the blog layout. Has anyone had this issue? Help? Thanks ;)
